# Conversion from std::future<void> to non-scalar std::future<bool> raised error

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

The method `validate(std::string& request, int& id)` returns `bool`.

When I use this syntax the compilation finishes:

```
auto task_1 = std::async([&]{ validate(request, id); });
```

However, when I use `std::future<bool>`, the compilation fails :

```
std::future<bool> task_1 = std::async([&]{ Internal::validate(request, id); });
```

The error is:

> error: conversion from ‘`std::future<void>`’ to non-scalar type
>   ‘`std::future<bool>`’ requested

What is wrong here? I want to check that:

```
task_1.get() == true
```

Comment: Your lambda doesn't return anything, voting to close as a typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
std::future<bool> task_1 = std::async([&]{ Internal::validate(request, id); });
```

to

```
std::future<bool> task_1 = std::async([&]{ return Internal::validate(request, id); });
```

your lambda didn't return a `bool`; so it cannot be used as a future source of a `bool`.

If `validate` doesn't return `bool`, it should be a `future<void>`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you need to actually return a value from the lambda for the function to have a return type. Since you're not doing that the return type of `std::async` is `std::future<void>`.

`std::async([&]{ return Internal::validate(request, id); });` would result in `std::future<bool>`